# Would it be possible to run a Java applet in a Java app on Android?

Tags: java, android, applet

I am new to creating Java apps for Android, and I already know that you cannot run Java applets within a web browser on Android.

With that being said, is there anyway you could run an applet within another app on Android?

Is there anyway to run the applet in a new activity for the app?

Comment: Pretty sure applets require a web browser with appropriate plugins that Android doesn't have. What does your applet do that isn't available to code into Android?

Answer (score 0):

> is there anyway you could run an applet within another app on android?

Applets use APIs, like AWT for their UI, that do not exist in Android. You would need to see if anyone has created an applet container for Android (possible but unlikely) or rewrite the applet.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can´t.

Java  use Java Virtual Machine.
Android use Dalvyk or ART.(Another virtual machine.)

Android use Java to code and some same classes... but has own classes to some stuff.

Comment: The reasons you have given are not sufficient.